# What happens to the port when IP changes?

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tftp

I have small TFTP server running on port 8080. It is an Android application. When I try to connect it while being on Ethernet, it works seamlessly. However, when I switch from Ethernet to Wifi. I get 'Connection refuse' error. Or sometime it displays first page and then when I try to navigate, it crashes with same error. So, what do I need to do if the IP changes ? Do i need to restart the TFTP server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a wifi network error due to some radio interference or to some problem with the hardware. The connection refused error is probably the effect to some timeout that get triggered on after a (partially) failed attempt to establish a communication channel. This is why you sometime can see a part of the requested document.

I'm almost sure you are using a wireless router to allow the two device to communicate each other. Did you try a different router and/or a totally different place (a friend's house, for example)?

Comment: Thanks for the insight. And yes, you are right, I am using wireless router to allow communication. I have tried with different router but not at different place (I guess you meant to say different network, right ?).

Comment: No, I actually mean a different place: different walls, different floors, different furniture, different type and position of doors. These are the element that can hide a possible element that interfers with the wifi radio signal. Not to mention all of the electric and radio equipments you can find in your house/office... :-)